# Powerpoint automation

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

How can i color the xAxis labels in a MSGraph Chart

Answer (score 2):

Answer for MS PowerPoint 2007:

Right click on the x-Axis inside the graph. Select `Font -> Font Color` and select the desired color for your labels.